# plotly dash datatable, string formatter

Tags: python, plotly-dash

Is it possible to specify formatter string for display in dash dataTable? I have a column with large numbers. I want to display them as '123.3K', '23M', but still be able to sort them correctly.

There was a thread on plotly forum a year ago but the conclusion there was "no solution yet".

https://community.plot.ly/t/dash-datatable-formatter-string/6328

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_table
from dash_table.Format import Format, Scheme
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

df = pd.DataFrame({"numbers": [123300, 23000000]})

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id="typing_formatting_1",
            data=df.to_dict("records"),
            columns=[
                {
                    "id": "numbers",
                    "name": "Formatted Numbers",
                    "type": "numeric",
                    "format": Format(precision=4, scheme=Scheme.decimal_si_prefix),
                },
            ],
        )
    ]
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server()
```

Result:

[image: formatted numbers]

Sources:

- https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/data-formatting
- https://dash.plotly.com/datatable/typing